# Find all users having rented every car in SQL

Tags: sql, database

> Find all users having rented every car in SQL

The database has the following structure (the primary keys are in bold):

- `rent` (**`People`, `cars`, `Daterent`**, `ExpectedReturnDate`, `EffectiveReturnDate`)
- `Lateness` (**`People`, `cars`, `Daterent`**, `LatenessFee`)

My attempt:

```
SELECT FROM rent 
WHERE FORALL cars EXISTS Daterent
```

Can you help me expressing correctly such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've provided, the following works.

First, you want to determine how many different/unique cars there are:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT car) FROM rent)
```

Next, you want to SELECT those people who have rented every different/unique car - so one way to do this is by checking that the `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` cars for each person is the same as the `COUNT` of all `DISTINCT` cars:

```
SELECT people
FROM rent 
GROUP BY people
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT car) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT car) FROM rent)
```